# Is my way to install an AES encrypted partition good or bad?

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, loop-device

I would want to install a partition encrypted with AES **using a loop-device**.

So first, **I install the partition and its files system.**

1. `fdisk /dev/sda`
2. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdaX` (with "sdaX" the created partition by `fdisk`)
3. `mount /dev/sdaX <mount_directory>`

Then I create text files, images, etc. in `mount_directory`.

Finally, **I use a loop-device**.

1. `losetup -e aes /dev/loop0 /dev/sda<X>`
2. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0`
3. `mount /dev/loop0 <mount_directory>`
4. I use `<mount_directory>` (creation again of files, images, delete them...) but a password will be asked because I encrypted `/dev/loop0`
5. `unmount <mount_directory>`
6. `losetup -d /dev/loop0`